# Beer in my terminal: HOW?

Tags: fonts, console, homebrew

Brew puts a picture of a tiny beer in my terminal?!?![image: Brew in my terminal]

How does it do this? I don't even. But I need to know, because all of my future command line applications must also put tiny pictures in their output.

Comment: I would suspect this has to do with the font. What font are you using?

Comment: I suspect it's to do with the package being called 'brew'

Comment: I can't reproduce this with my copy of homebrew. It is pretty cool, are you using some special terminal application?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is probably just a unicode character. In my terminal, this works:

```
$ echo -e "Hello, \xF0\x9F\x8D\xBA"
Hello,
```

Comment: There's a unicode for beer? Us techy types know what's important!

Answer (score 5):

It's outputting Unicode character U+1F37A (BEER MUG), which is in the "Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs" (*aka*. Emoji) range.

Comment: Even  (U+1F4A9 - PILE OF POO).

Comment: @duskwuff Does that poo have a face? Wh... bu... why?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as discussed in [this blog](http://www.kirsle.net/blog/kirsle/please-don-t-use-emoji), we linux user's won't be able to appreciate the humour of this question as well as those of you running OSX...

To see what emoji your operating system supports, check out [wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) on the subject.

Comment: I can help you install a modern unix on your laptop, if you like.

Comment: not that hard to get emoji fonts working on the terminal: https://gist.github.com/robotslave/4633393